# Get the database user using JPA and set in the Entity Attribute

Tags: java, jpa, oracle11g, persistence

I am new in JPA. I have these table in Database which the column Created_By is not nullable. The problem is I am having a constraint issue as this value is not nullable.

Database: Oracle 11G
App Server: IBM Websphere
Using JNDI for the datasource
Transaction Table:

```
Customer_Id | Amount | Status  | Created_BY   | Created_Date  |
1           | 10    | Pending  |   (USER)     |  (new Date()) |
```

In my Java codes, I do not set the CreatedBy and attributes as they are defaulted in my Database script where in the date is SYSDATE.

```
Customers customer = new Customer();
customer.setCustomerId(12324);
customer.setAmount(10);
customer.setStatus(StatusType.PENDING.getName());
customer.setCreatedDate(new Date());
```

Is there anyway I can the user from the DB using JPA? not using the native query "Select user from Dual".

Comment: Your question is really not clear..what do you want to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the connection user name by following the code below.

```
 EntityManagerFactoryInfo info = (EntityManagerFactoryInfo) em.getEntityManagerFactory();
 String userName = info.getPersistenceUnitInfo().getNonJtaDataSource().getConnection().getMetaData().getUserName();
```